# html one page template to wordpress conversion

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I seriously need help of you guyz, I got a project of wordpress at my office and the client has selected one page html template and asked to convert it to wordpress. I know how to convert html to worpdress normal themes but as the theme is only one page with multiple divs acting as page. I lost my mind how to do it.

I am sorry because this is not a how to platform but i need a starter point.

The theme markup is as follows

```
<!--Home Page
=============================-->
<div id="home" class="item">
                <!--<img src="assets/img/2.jpg" alt="The Spice Lounge" class="fullBg">-->
                <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="header_details">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header_icons accura-header-block accura-hidden-2xs">
                        <ul class="accura-social-icons accura-stacked accura-jump accura-full-height accura-bordered accura-small accura-colored-bg clearFix">
                        <li id="1"><a href="#" class="accura-social-icon-facebook circle"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="2"><a href="#" class="accura-social-icon-twitter circle"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="3"><a href="#" class="accura-social-icon-gplus circle"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="4"><a href="#" class="accura-social-icon-pinterest circle"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="5"><a href="#" class="accura-social-icon-linkedin circle"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                <div class="call">
                    <div class="home_address">
                        #12 FIFTH MAIN STREET,<br> NY 10307, USA.<br>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;+1 123 456 7890
                </div>
            </div>
<!-- Mainheader Menu Section -->    
<div class="mainheaderslide" id="slide">
    <div id="mainheader" class="header">
        <div class="menu-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
        <div class="header-table col-md-12 header-menu">

        <!--  Logo section -->
        <div class="brand"><a href="#home" class="nav-link">The <span> Spice </span>Lounge</a></div>
        <!--  // Logo section -->

<!-- Home Page Menu section -->
                        <nav class="main-nav">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-toggle"></a>
                            <ul  id="home_nav" class="nav">
                            <li><span class="nav-link selected1">Main</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu<span class="sub-toggle"></span></a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#" class="panel">Menu 1 <i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right direction"></i> <span class="sub-toggle"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#menuwithoutimage2" class="nav-link">Menu without image2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#menu1" class="nav-link">Menu without image</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#menu2" class="nav-link">Menu with image (Big)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#menu3" class="nav-link">Menu with image (small)</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#menu4" class="nav-link">Menu pdf</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#menu5" class="nav-link">Menu Toggle</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#special" class="nav-link">Today Specials</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#weeklymenu" class="nav-link">Weekly Menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#loungebar" class="nav-link">Lounge Bar</a></li>                    
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pages<span class="sub-toggle"></span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#chefbio" class="nav-link">Chef-Bio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#giftcards" class="nav-link">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#locations" class="nav-link">Our Locations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#privatedining" class="nav-link">Private Dining</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#catering" class="nav-link">Catering</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>
                            <li><a href="#gallery" class="nav-link">Gallery</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="#event" class="nav-link">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#reservation" class="nav-link">Reservation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact<span class="sub-toggle"></span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contactform" class="nav-link">Contact Form</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>    
                            </ul>
                      </nav>
<!--  // Home Page Menu section -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <!-- // Mainheader Menu Section -->
        </div>
            <!-- VEGAS  -->
    <div id="vegas_page">
<div class="banner_bg1">
<div class="ban_pattern_bg3">
<div class="clearfix">
<!--Vegas slider-->
<div class="clearfix" id="home_ban">
<div class="col-md-12">

        <div id="anchor1"></div>
        <div id="home-fullWidth" class="clear">
            <div>
                <ul class="slider-controls">
                    <li><a id="vegas-next" class="s-next" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="vegas-prev" class="s-prev" href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-title title-fullWidth">
            <div class="title-container">
                <div class="welcome hideme dontHide element_from_bottom">The <span>Spice</span> Lounge</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sliding_title">Come hungry. Leave happy.</li>
                    <li>Delicious Food </li>
                    <li>Best Taste Great Price</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logx"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- // Vegas slider -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- /VEGAS  -->
        </div>
        </div>

<!--About us
=============================-->       
<div id="about" class="item" style="background-color:#999999;">
                <img src="assets/img/12.jpg" alt="The Spice Lounge" class="fullBg">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="content_overlay"></div>
                        <div class="content_inner">
<div class="row contentscroll">
    <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-6 empty">&nbsp;</div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 content_text">
                          <h1>About Us</h1>
                          <div class="clearfix pad_top13">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p class="row">
                                <span class="bold">Specializes in Non-veg , 65, Thanthuri, Sandwich, 65 smoked sandwich.</span><br/><br/> Our team of highly qualified professionals headed by an experienced Chef. Lnim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.<br /><br />

Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo. Duis aute dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla  do tempore ercitationem ut labore. et dolore magna aliqua.                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="right_content ">
                                    <div class="sub_title">
                                        <h4>Opening hours:</h4>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="hour_table">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td class="days">mon - Fri</td>
                                          <td>9:00am - 4:00pm</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td class="days">Sat</td> 
                                          <td>9:00am - 2:00pm</td>      
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td class="days">Sun</td> 
                                          <td>8:30am - 1:00pm</td>      
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="sub_title">
                                        <h4>book your table:</h4>
                                    </div>

                                <p>
                                    We welcome walk-in guests,online at<br/><br><a class="button nav-link" href="#reservation">Book table</a>                               </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
<!-- // About us
```

=============================-->

Its a bit of code to illustrate how the theme is designed its actually a div with an id that represents the page.

Here is the link for the template

http://www.accurathemes.com/tf/The_Spice_Lounge/v_1_2/site/white-version/index-vegas-another-version.htm

I will be really thankful for your help as after searching a lot stackoverflow is my last hope :)

Regards
Raheel

Comment: can you please post some more information about how you end up doing this? I'm facing the same issue and want to know how to start

Comment: What i did is, I made single file index.php and i used get_pages function to loop through all pages. In my index.php page i have div elements like div#home, div#about etc so in side my loop i managed to put the content of page in their respective div. The rest is done via jquery sliding stuff and all.

Comment: Ok that make sense. How can i make part of each page changeable (text mostly) from the wordpress console?

Comment: Well what i did, Inside a loop of get_pages i was getting page_id and i fetch content against that id from wp_posts table and dump them on run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop this one page website in WordPress using this WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/

Comment: I've converted it by separating all divs into pages in wordpress admin and on index.php get_pages function. The rest of the work is already handled by javascript. thanks